# C++ dynamic return type with special case

Tags: c++, dynamic, polymorphism, telegram, mtproto

I'm trying to do something like a runtime-defined function return type in C++.
I have four different classes (actually, a lot more, but let's make this problem simple), the class `Factory`, the class `Parent` and two child classes `FirstChild` and `SecondChild`. Both `FirstChild` and `SecondChild` extend `Parent`. In the actual code there are many more child classes, but they work the same.
In the `Factory` class, I have the `read` method, that needs an `int ID` input and returns one of the child classes.
Normally what could be done, and that's what's rederred [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32710025/c-dynamic-return-type), is that I could return the `Parent` method with a pointer and use that, but the fact is that the child classes have some parameters that are not in common with the `Parent` class.
Also, when I call the method `Factory::read` with the `ID`, I do not know prior what will be the child result class that I'll have, but I have a list of possibilities of what it can be (remember that in the actual code there are way more than only two child classes), so I can't do a `dynamic_cast`.
For those who want to know, I'm trying to make a MTProto (the protocol of Telegram) client in C++, and I'm stuck with the parsing of the TLObjects.
If anyone has a solution or an alternative path to do what I'm trying to do, any help will be gladly appreciated!

Comment: the accepted answer mentions `boost::variant`. Meanwhile there is `std::variant`

Comment: ...hence I think this is a duplicate of the question you link

Comment: I already wrote in the post why the post I linked is not a solution for my problem, the child classes have members not shared with the parent class and I don't know the result type of the Factory::read function, so I can't use std::variable as I don't know the right type to use with std::get (i think)

Comment: ok, not a dupe then, but then I don't understand the question. Somehow the function does need to know what type to return at some point

Comment: why cant you use `std::variant::visit` or `std::variant::get_if`?

Comment: btw on a second read you are explaining why a common base is not an option, but " I have a list of possibilities of what it can be" means that `std::variant` should be fine

Comment: Why, exactly, does "members not shared with the Parent class" preclude you from returning a `Parent*` pointing to a child class?

Comment: @Botje because I won't be able to access it as the compiler doesn't know the exact child class, and that's also why I can't do a dynamic_cast

Comment: The compiler doesn't need to know. You can substitute a `FirstChild*` for a `Parent*`.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number on a second thought std::get_if could be a suitable solution that I didn't see before, I'll try and mark this question as duplicate if that works